# prevent form submission if form fields are not filled

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't want user to submit if field is not filled

Comment: Using a simple google search you can find the answer for this. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  Html5 `required` attribute directly in the input field, so your snippet become:

```
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
      Name: <input type="text" name="fname" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_required.asp

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
let form = document.forms['myForm'];
let input = form.querySelector('input[name="fname"]');
form.addEventListner('submit',(e) => {
  if(!input.length){
    e.preventDefault():
  }
})
```